# How to implement class with virtual method on the fly

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

The title is a bit misleading, but I don't know how to phrase the problem in one line.

Basically, I'm using a library that has the definition of this class:

```
class UCallbackWrapper {
   public:
      virtual UCallbackAction operator ()(const UMessage &)=0;
      virtual ~UCallbackWrapper() {}
};
```

And I'm using a function of the library that has this declaration:

```
 UCallbackID setCallback(UCallbackWrapper & callback, const char * tag);
```

So basically, it receives as argument (a reference to) an object of type `UCallbackWrapper`.

If in the c++ file with the main function of the program I declare a function with the right prototype, it lets me pass it to the `setCallback` function, like this:

```
UCallbackAction onImageCallback(const UMessage &msg)
{
    // Some code here
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{       
   setCallback(onImageCallback, "something"); // This works
}
```

Now, I would like to create a class instead, and use the setCallback function inside that class, passing a function that is member of that class. But if I do that, then the prototype of the function goes from

```
UCallbackAction onImageCallback(const UMessage &msg)
```

to

```
UCallbackAction (myClass::*)onImageCallback(const UMessage &msg)
```

and I can no longer pass that to setCallback.

I tried creating a lambda function, like this:

```
std::function<UCallbackAction(const UMessage &)> onImageCallback = [&] (const UMessage &msg) -> UCallbackAction {
    // Code here
};

setCallback(onImageCallback, "something");
```

but still doesn't work, the compiler says:

error: no matching function for call to 'USyncClient::setCallback(std::function&, const char [8])'
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::function' to 'UCallbackWrapper&'

So, I thought about creating a class that inherits from UCallbackWrapper and implements the virtual method (kinda like what I would do in Java), but I don't know how to do that in C++ (or of it's possible).

Can you guys help me out? Or maybe point out something that I'm doing wrong with the lambda function, or a workaround anyway.

Comment: `setCallback()` is declared to take a `UCallbackWrapper&`, yet you call it with a function pointer and say that this works. How come? Is there another overload you haven't told us about?

Comment: None that I could find, but the library code is a mess... might be that I'm missing something. I'm not very familiar with C++ and most things confuse me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a class that implements the virtual function. You could also give it the ability to register itself as the callback.

```
class MyCallback : public UCallbackWrapper {
public:
    UCallbackAction operator ()(const UMessage& message) override {
        // Some code here...
    }
    void registerAsCallback() {
        setCallback(*this, "something");  
    }
};
```

Just beware that due to the design of the library API it is your responsibility to ensure the lifetime of your class while the library might be using it:

```
int main() {
    MyCallback mcb;
    mcb.registerAsCallback();

    // Cause library to use callback here...
}
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BXp4Qj4xQjQVl8hV)

Comment: I didn't want to explicitly create a class just for that, but I guess it's the easiest way to do it. So be it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class F>
struct UCallbackWrapperImpl:UCallbackWrapper {
  F f;
  virtual UCallbackAction operator ()(const UMessage & m)final override{
    return f(m);
  }
};
using upUCallback=std::unique_ptr<UCallbackWrapper>;
template<class F>
upUCallback MakeUCallback(F&& f){
  return upUCallback(new UCallbackWrapperImpl<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<F>(f)});
}
```

Pass a lambda to `MakeUCallback` and get a smart pointer to a `UCallbackWrapper`.

`MakeUCallback` retuens a smart pointer to the interface the api expects.  Store this smart pointer for the lifetime of the callback.  It will delete the callback object when it finally goes out of scope -- you can extend this by `std::move`ing it to another `upUCallback`.

To use the api, dereference the returned `upUCallback`.

Note that the api is strange in that it takes a *reference* to a pure virtual interface.  I do not know what crack those api designers are on, bjt that is not a good sign.  You may have to investigate what lifetime management the api expects in their `UCallbackWrapper` classes: how long are they supposed to last, who deletes them, etc.

In C++ you should *always* be aware of object lifetime requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Honestly I don't really understand this code, but I've tried anyway. Sadly it doesn't work, it says: "no known conversion for argument 1 from 'upUCallback {aka std::unique_ptr<UCallbackWrapper>}' to 'UCallbackWrapper&'"

Comment: @Beriol it is a smart pointer.  Store it for the lifetime of the callback.  Dereference it like a pointer to get a reference to oass to the api.  It is very strange to have an api that takes a reference to a virtual interface btw.  Details added to question.